# When to use automatic properties?

Tags: c#, .net, security

So, I have an encryption key in my code like:

```
private const string _keyc = "blahblahblah";

private static string _key
{
     get { return "blahblahblah"; }
}
```

After compilation, on `ILDasm`, I do notice that I can just see the value of the constant directly, but not in the second case. However, I can still see the key in `ldstr` under `hidebysig...get_key()`

ILSpy however obtained back the source code exactly the way I wrote it.

So here, I'm wondering, does it really make sense to use an auto property here? Are there any other advantages in using auto properties? Specifically in this type of simple case, would it be advisable to use an auto property? Thanks!

Comment: Auto properties are just syntactic sugar, no?

Comment: Read-only properties cannot be automatic, so they wouldn't be applicable in this case anyway.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm beginning 2 agree, but maybe I might hear a more interesting opinion :)

Comment: Maybe you're asking for some other use, but please do not ever include encryption keys in your code like this :)

Comment: This isn't an automatic property, it's just a property.  An auto property would be `public static string Key {get;set;}`

Comment: @AlvaroRodriguez: It's a hobby app so I don't really care. Though I'm still interested, what would you suggest?

Comment: Key management is its own field, but at least use DPAPI http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx

Comment: I just read an article by Jon Skeet, that really seems to provide expanded solid views on the topic. http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use automatic properties only when:

- The property is read-write; that is, it defines both `get` and `set` accessors.  If you are only defining one accessor, you cannot use automatic properties.  (Note that you *can* define a `private set` accessor on an automatic property if you want the property to be read-only from code outside of the class, but read-write from inside the class.)
- You do not need to do any verification in the setter -- that is, all values of the property type are valid.
- You do not need to initialize the backing field directly, but instead will set the property from a constructor (or just leave the default value in the field).
- You never need to reference the backing field directly, for example as a `ref` or `out` parameter.  In particular, this will prevent you from using the `System.Threading.Interlocked` methods on the field.
- The name of the field is not important.  (Serialization is a case where it might be considered important.)

Based on your example, you are implementing a read-only property (one with no setter).  You cannot use automatic properties in this case, unless you use a pattern like this:

```
class Example
{
    public static string SomeProperty { get; private set; }

    static Example()
    {
        SomeProperty = "some value";
    }
}
```

However, just returning the constant value from a getter is much less complex, and should be preferred:

```
class Example
{
    public static string SomeProperty
    {
        get { return "some value"; }
    }
}
```

This code is clear and to the point.  Automatic properties are supposed to make your code more readable.  In this case they would actually obfuscate intent, so I would not use one here.

---

Note that the property in your example code is *not* an automatic property at all; it's just a standard property.  Automatic properties declare a getter and setter, but do not provide an implementation.

Comment: In other words, when you are implementing a read-only variable, it's much better to stick to readability and simplicity?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata It's *always* better to stick to readability and simplicity. Every piece of code should be as simple as possible, and no simpler.